# Did the number of rods changed from ancient time?

Tags: human-biology, eyes, adaptation

Correct me if I am wrong, but I know that rods work under limited light conditions only.

But now we are in a world that always have lights everywhere unlike ancient time when humans had to deal with darkness.

I also know that the humans adapt to its living conditions.

Since our eye only uses the cones and don't use rods often, will the number of rods decrease because of this?

Comment: Such evolutionary changes happen very slow - and the availability of light happened very recently in evolutionary terms. So if such a adaptation happens, it will take quite a while to happen. If at all.